# Discrete Math Logic Proofs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Probably for my Discrete Mathematics class, been looking over it the past couple hours, and haven't come up with any answers. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Prove that if b^2-4c < 0, then there is no such $x \in\mathbb R$ such that x^2+bx+c=0

Answer (score 1):

Two complex roots of a polynomial of degree 2:
$$ax^2+bx+c$$
are given by the formula
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
and cannot be real for $\Delta=b^2-4ac<0$. In you case $a=1$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there were such x. Then

$0=x^{2}+bx+c=(x-\frac{b}{2})^{2}-\frac{b^{2}}{4}+c$

So $(x-\frac{b}{2})^{2}=\frac{b^{2}}{4}-c=\frac{1}{4}(b^{2}-4c)<0$

which is not possible for real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Add and substract $\frac{b^2}{4}$ to the equation. Use this to complete the square.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that if $x^2+bx+c=0$ then either $$x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2,\text{ or }x=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}}2.$$ Does the root of a negative number exist in the real numbers?